# dynamic loading of page content in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

how to do For an application that uses dynamic page loading, the app launches and loads only the first screen. Based upon user interaction a new screen can be displayed by retrieving the new HTML content and replacing the current screen with it  in jquery mobile with out loosing its styles(how to load the diffrent page contents in one page div when a click event is takes place )

page name is a.html

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Include meta tag to ensure proper rendering and touch zooming -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Include jQuery Mobile stylesheets -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <!-- Include the jQuery library -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Include the jQuery Mobile library -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Insert Page Title Here</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content" id="container">
    <p>Insert Content Here</p>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>Insert Footer Text Here</h1>
  </div>
</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

and i want to change the  content(id=container) with another content  in different html page 
that is
page name b.html with out loosing css styling of jquery mobile

```
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>I Am Now A Mobile Developer!!</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Show us some code/markup. Tell us what you have already tried. Which part exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: added code snippets please help me out

Comment: After replacing the content, call $("#container").enhanceWithin(); to initialize the jQM widgets in the new content.

Comment: how to replace the content ?

Comment: use .html(): http://api.jquery.com/html/